# react-query: useMutation, useQuery and isLoading, how to prevent showing old data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I'm using `react-query` in my React app to fetch and mutate data. When I click a button to mutate the data, I need the button to be disabled and spinner to appear until the new mutated data is returned.

To achieve this, I'm using the `isLoading` and `isMutating` flags provided by `useMutation` and `useQuery` hooks.

```
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const {
    isLoading,
    error,
    data: todos,
  } = useQuery<Todo[]>("todos", fetchTodos);
  const { mutate, isLoading: isMutating } = useMutation(addTodo, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries("todos");
    },
  });

  const handleAddTodo = () => {
    if (!todos) return;
    mutate({ id: todos.length + 1, title: "New Todo", completed: false });
  };

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>Error fetching todos.</div>;
  if (!todos) return <div>Unexpected missing data</div>;

  return (
    <>
      <button disabled={isMutating} onClick={handleAddTodo}>
        Add Todo
      </button>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <li key={todo.id}>
            {todo.completed ? "☑" : "☐"} - {todo.title}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
```

When I click on the button to save data, for a brief moment, "Loading..." appears, then "loading" disappears, but old data are still displayed. Then again "loading" appears, and new data appear after that.

- clicked button
- a mutation request is sent
- `isMutating` is true, button is disabled
- a mutation request is completed, cache is invalidated
- `isMutating` is false, button is enabled
- a query request is sent, `isLoading` is still false, old data is displayed
- a query request finishes, new data appears

How do I disable the button until the new data comes in?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62582184/react-query-show-loading-spinner-while-fetching-data

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR `isLoading` of `useQuery` is useless for showing spinners, use `isFetching` if you don't need background loading and need proper spinners**

I should've read [documentation on `useQuery`](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery) more carefully.

The `isLoading` property of the `useQuery` hook only indicates that the query is loading if there is no cached data available. If there is cached data available, the hook will return that data immediately and `isLoading` will be set to false. This results in old data being displayed briefly before the new data is fetched.

What I need is `isFetching` property. It indicates whether the query is currently fetching new data, regardless of whether there is cached data available. So using isFetching solves the issue.

Probably, I should use an overlay based on `isFetching` and the data shown based on `isLoading`. The button should be disabled based on `isMutating` and `isFetching`.

Also, watch [a demo from `react-query` creator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seU46c6Jz7E) where he mentions that he doesn't like multiple spinners going everywhere and prefers optimistic background updates.

react-query v4 (a new version published in organization) describes the need for two separate statuses, `status` and `fetchStatus`:
https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/queries#why-two-different-states

The main reason is ability to do loading in the background while displaying the cached (stale) version.

Answer (score 3):

if you return the result from `invalidateQueries` (which is a Promise) from the `onSuccess` callback, your mutation will stay in `loading` state until that Promise has resolved as well:

```
onSuccess: () => {
  return queryClient.invalidateQueries("todos");
},
```

with that, you only need to disable the button while the mutation is in-flight (in loading state)